# Laravel - hasMany() and belongsTo() not working correctly for me in @foreach loop

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I got following error when I try to use this on my page

> Trying to get property of non-object

I have two tables:

```
cvicenis
  id
  title
  body
  category_id
categories
  id
  name
```

My Cviceni model:

```
namespace App;    
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cviceni extends Model
{
    public function category() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'id');
    }
}
```

My Category model:

```
namespace App;    
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function cviceni()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Cviceni', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $cviceni = Cviceni::all();
    return view('excercises.index', compact('cviceni'));
}
```

My index.blade:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <h1>Přehled cvičení</h1>
            @if(count($cviceni) > 0)
            <ul>
                @foreach ($cviceni as $c)
                    <li> {{ $c->category->name }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
            @else
                <h2>There is nothing to display</h2>
            @endif
        </div><!-- end of column -->
    </div><!-- end of row -->
@endsection
```

If I use in my controller `Cviceni::find(1)` then I can get the value from $cviceni->category->name 
But not when I use a `foreach` loop.
Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Cviceni model, I think you set up the foreign key is wrong. Your foreign key in the table is category_id, while you set up the relationship with foreign key is id. Try to replace the category() relationship with follow

```
public function category() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to eager load the models if you need them:

```
public function index()
{
    $cviceni = Cviceni::with("category")->get();
    return view('excercises.index', compact('cviceni'));
}
```

Comment: That did not help :( Still got the same error when I trie to run it through the foreach loop... even if i try something like `$cviceni[0]->category->name`